# Alfresco : Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server

Tags: mysql, alfresco

I am new with Alfresco Comunity, i have trouble when i tried to configure database. i follow the step from [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/mysql-config.html)  but it's not working i still got an error : "**Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server**"

this is my `C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco-global.properties`

```
###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################

dir.root=C:/alfresco-community/alf_data

alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http

### database connection properties ###
#db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
#db.username=alfresco
#db.password=admin
#db.name=alfresco
#db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
#db.pool.max=275
#db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

db.driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfrescoaio?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 

db.username=root
db.password=123abc

db.name=alfrescoaio
db.host=localhost
db.port=3306
db.pool.max=275

user.name.caseSensitive=true




# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=UNKNOWN

### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21

### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500

### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=C:/alfresco-community/libreoffice/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=C:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe

jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=C:/alfresco-community/libreoffice/App/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634

### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false

### License location ###
dir.license.external=C:/alfresco-community

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost
solr.port.ssl=8443

### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false

### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false

### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false
```

error in log :

```
rnate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver'
```

Any one can help me how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you post logs from tomcat?

Comment: What version of Alfresco Community are you using? Have you downloaded the source and are building it yourself or are you using an installer? What database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Did you create the database in MySQL named "alfrescoaio" and grant access to a user called "root" with a password of "123abc"? Use a mysql client or similar tool to validate that you can connect to that database with those creds.

Comment: @DaveDraper i'm using alfresco v 201602, yes i use installer, i want to connect to MYSQL

Comment: @JeffPotts yes,i've made that database. my database name is 'alfrescoaio' and username is root and the password is 123abc.

Answer (score 1):

The Alfresco installer ships with PostgreSQL. When it is installed it will place the PostgreSQL driver (postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar) in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib.

If you are switching to a different database you need to make sure the new database driver is available. Your error message seems to indicate it isn't.

Go look in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib and see if you have a file named mysql-connector-java-*.jar. If you don't, download it from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), then place the JAR in this directory and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Link](http://34codefactory.blogspot.in/2017/08/cannot-find-alfresco-repository-on-this.html)

Please check you completed these steps :

- copy `mysql-connector-java-5.x.x` jar into `<alfresco>\tomcat\lib` folder.
- `max_connections = 275` in `<MySQL>\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini`
- Create user **alfresco** and assign all privileges.
- Create schema `alfresco` in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Database Technology of alfresco, you must create a Database schema with the name `alfresco`.

Because when Alfresco is started at that time it will find the database and create some table based on that schema.

> http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/mysql-config.html