# Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server

Tags: alfresco

I have a new installation of Alfresco CE on my server (Ubuntu 16.04), but get an error

```
Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)
```

The tomcat log has the following error over and over

```
ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-11] Tracking failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04310291 api/solr/aclchangesets return status:404
```

Any one can help me how to fix this ?

Comment: You have most probably some error preventing your repo from booting up! Can you check the full log for other (earlier) errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was an authentication issue with Postgres (stupid me). I missed the error message between all the others

Comment: please try to reinstall alfresco. and refer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304759/alfresco-cannot-find-alfresco-repository-on-this-server