# How and where can I give Alfresco all the drivers it needs?

Tags: alfresco

I have an Alfresco installation I'm trying to get to work.

When I run, it displays an error:

> Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)

[Alfresco : Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304759/alfresco-cannot-find-alfresco-repository-on-this-server) has the same error message and was apparently answered by saying "You're trying to use MySQL instead of [the default] Postgres; install the requisite MySQL JDBC driver."

I have a setup that was intended to use Postgres (I'll happily use MySQL instead if someone tells how to do that and it works). $TOMCAT_HOME/lib contains the following, including what looks like one Postgres driver:

```
annotations-api.jar  jasper.jar                    tomcat-dbcp.jar
catalina-ant.jar     jsp-api.jar                   tomcat-i18n-es.jar
catalina-ha.jar      org                           tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
catalina.jar         postgresql-9.4.1211.jre7.jar  tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
catalina-tribes.jar  servlet-api.jar               tomcat-jdbc.jar
ecj-4.4.jar          tomcat7-websocket.jar         tomcat-util.jar
el-api.jar           tomcat-api.jar                websocket-api.jar
jasper-el.jar        tomcat-coyote.jar
```

Relatedly, I have:

```
$ /usr/local/websites/alfresco/java/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

What can/should I do next?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory is the proper directory for your database driver JARs.

The other file that is very important is your alfresco-global.properties file. It resides in $TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes.

If this is a manual install of Alfresco (meaning you set up Tomcat on your own) you may have to set up the /shared classloader which involves updating Tomcat's configuration.

The [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com) have more info.